# C#, convert columns to one row in a list

Tags: c#, list

Ok, here is the situation: I've got a C# partial class that returns a list of objects, using the .Select().ToList() functionality.

I get how this works.

The issue that I'm running into, though, is that there are four properties in the class that I need to use in one column. To compound this, each column is supposed to be tied to a row, which displays a lot of redundant information.

An example helps:

I currently have this, let's say, as my class:

```
public class MyClass{
public string PersonName {get;set;}
public string PersonAddress {get;set;}
public string Field1 {get;set;}
public string Field2 {get;set;}
public string Field3 {get;set;}
public string Field4 {get;set;}
}
```

That gives you a basic idea of my class. My original suggestion was do set the code up where it did this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Field 1<br>Field 2<br>Field 3<br>Field 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Which makes sense.

However, those above me have decided that they want a layout like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Field 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Field 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Field 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>Field 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Where, if you'll notice, Name and Address are *redundant* for each row.

So, how could I do this in C#?

Comment: How are you generating the HTML now?  You can either  change your generation code to repeat the properties or project your list to a new type that splits one object into 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ [SelectMany method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate a list that contains 4 objects per a single `MyClass` object like this:

```
List<MyClass> list = ...

var result = list.SelectMany(x =>
    new[]
    {
        new {x.PersonAddress, x.PersonName, Value = x.Field1},
        new {x.PersonAddress, x.PersonName, Value = x.Field2},
        new {x.PersonAddress, x.PersonName, Value = x.Field3},
        new {x.PersonAddress, x.PersonName, Value = x.Field4}
    }).ToList();
```

This will return a list of anonymous type objects.

Each one of these objects will contain a `PersonAddress`, a `PersonName`, and a `Value` property.

You can then loop over them to generate the HTML that you want.